# magento 2.2 add validation to checkout region input field

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, validation

following this post ([Magento 2.2 Input field validation on Checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227390/magento-2-2-input-field-validation-on-checkout-page))

I can successfully add validation on the company field. But when I apply that to the `region field`, it doesn't work anymore. By **"doesnt work"** I mean that I get no validation message at all, I can write whatever I want in the region field and I get no red message.

**What I need is to validate the region field so that the user can write only 2 characters. How can I do that?**

> What I did:

```
1. created checkout_index_index.xml in my theme under app/design/frontend/Theme/default/Magento_Checkout/layout
2. Add the code specified in the post mentioned above
3. substitute "company" with "region"
```

**Final xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
      <body>
    <referenceBlock  name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <!-- To affect the shipping address fields -->
                                                    <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                                            <item name="region" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                                                                        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">9</item>
                                                                        <item name="letters-only" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        <item name="max-words" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>

                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

As I said, If I change **"region"** with **"company"**, it works perfectly. But I need to apply the validation to the **region field**. Any idea how to achieve this?

**Thanks**

Comment: Instead of region give as region_id not sure but guessing that would work out @Lounik

Comment: hi, thank you. I tried with region_id but unfortunately it doesn't work as well

Comment: try it vendor file to verify it then make it in your file @Lounik

Answer (score 0):

> Please go to admin

Store->Configuration->General->State Options(Select Your Region. You Want to required).

After Cache Flush.

Comment: I don't want it to be required. It's ok for it to be optional. What I want is that - if the customer fills it in - he can only write two letters.